# Get the selected month in fullcalendar.io Angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I have already tried using jquery using the below code,

```
  getMonth(){
    const date = $('#calendarOptions').fullCalendar('getCalendar');
    const monthInt = date.getMonth();
    // you now have the visible month as an integer from 0-11
 }
```

however I get an error message which says

```
Property 'fullCalendar' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.ts(2339)
```

Is there a way to directly access which month I am currently on using typescript?

I have also tried this

```
getMonth(){
  const calendarApi = this.calendarOptions.getApi();
  const currentDate = calendarApi.view.currentStart;

  console.log(currentDate); // result: current calendar start date
}
```

However, it says Property 'getApi' does not exist on type 'CalendarOptions'

Comment: if you give the full code of the page, it would be much simple for others to understand what's going on here. How do you init fullCalendar? 
`Property 'fullCalendar' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.ts(2339)` means typescript knows nothing about types in `jquery full calendar plugin`

Comment: Hi Mike. I have uploaded the entire code. I initialise the calendar by using the code "calendarOptions: CalendarOptions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the example form `Calendar API` section (almost the last one) of
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

Comment: I followed the guide but i get a "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getApi')".
I've added the updated code above.
The new method is called someMethod()

Comment: Have you seted `#calendar` as `<full-calendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>` in `./CalendarView.component.html`?

Comment: yes. its within a div though. Just tried it outside a div and it still doesnt work. i updated the full calendar package to the latest one.

Comment: It wasn't able to get the calendar options because the calendar was loading after the data had been received as it was doing an asynchronous call to an api. I put the     someMethod(); within the asynchronous subscribe method and now its showing me what month has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code below

```
    setTimeout(() => {
         const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
         const currentDate = calendarApi.view.currentStart;
      
         console.log(currentDate);
    }
```

This allows the calendar to load first and then you can access the getApi(). otherwise you will end up with a ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApi' of undefined error message.

Comment: Timeout is unreliable. If there's an asynchronous bit of code involved, just do this in the callback when that code completes.

Comment: I need the date before i do the asynchronous api call as it needs to know the date the user is currently on.

Comment: Yes but I don't mean that...if you are using a timeout to avoid the getApi being undefined, then it must be that the calendar is not initialised until after something asynchronous, so it's that you should be using the callback of... nothing to do with the API call